# codeigniter_i18n multi language

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual, codeigniter-url

I already read and follow the instruction from this link [codeigniter_i18 multilanguage](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) and it's works, but I have a little problem here, I don't know maybe at the routes config or the scripts.

for the example, this http://mysite.com is en default language in index of the site, but if I want to change different language for the instance dutch, so how to implement that I can get the url like this http://mysite.com/nl/

thanks in advance

Comment: hi you want to make nl as default language or you want to go on nl language from english language if so then use this from same library anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('nl'),'Display current page in French');

Comment: @umefarooq hi, I know about that, but not that one I asked, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using it in the path like actually makes things a lot more complicated, because you ALWAYS need the first segment to be a country code (so you need to use /en for English)

An easier method to consider is to set a session variable when they select a language, and do it "in the background":

In your MY_Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{               
parent::__construct();
$lang_code = ($this->session->userdata('lang_code'))? $this->session->userdata('lang_code'):'english';
$this->lang->load('project_launch', $lang_code);
$this->lang->load('project_launch_template', $lang_code);
$this->lang->load('project_launch_uploader', $lang_code);
}

function lang_select(){
    $lang_code = $this->input->post('lang_code');
    $this->session->set_userdata('lang_code', $lang_code );
}
```

and have your language selector (dropdown, little flags, whatever) call lang_select() to change the language & set the session variable; the construct will check the language each page load and load the appropriate language files

Comment: hi thank you for your quick response. So every time I change the language I have to set the session?

Comment: yes, exactly. but most people won't change language much - it isn't really a drain. Pages will check if the session is set & not re-set them. So not much impact on server